# Удалять файлы где дата отличается от сегодня

Tags: php

Нужно удалять файлы сравнивая с текущей датой.

Например, в папке создаются файлы:

```
2016-09-01_20-47-22.jpg
2016-09-01_19-42-02.gif
2016-08-23_20-37-42.png
2016-08-17_20-17-22.jpg
и т. д.
```

Нужно проверить и удалять все файлы где дата меньше текущей.

Спасибо.

Comment: все имена записываете в массив потом в цыкле у каждого элемента массива (имени файла) берете первых 10 символов и сопоставляете с текущей датой если не совпадает удаляете файл. Все просто.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$dir = "img/1/"; // папка где есть файлы c изображениями
$img_a = array(); // пустой массив
$dateNow = date("Y-m-d"); // дата на момент проверки в формате "2016-09-02"

if (is_dir($dir)){  // проверяем или указано папку
    if($od = opendir($dir)){ //открываем папку
        while(($file = readdir($od)) !== false){ // проверяем все файлы в папке
            if(strtolower(strstr($file, "."))===".jpg" || strtolower(strstr($file, "."))===".gif" || strtolower(strstr($file, "."))===".png"){ // проверяем или файлы имеют расширения .jpg, .gif, .png
            array_push($img_a, $file); // добавляем имена в массив
        }
    }
        closedir($od); //закриваем папку
    }
}

    for($i=0;$i<count($img_a);++$i){ //запускаем цыкл перебора масива
    $fileDate = substr($img_a[$i], 0, 10); //берем первые 10 символов имени

    if($fileDate != $dateNow){ // проверяем если дата файла не соответствует дате на момент проверки то
        echo 'изображение '.$img_a[$i].' не имеет текущую дату <br/>'; //указываем какая картинка не имеет текущей даты
        unlink($dir.$img_a[$i]); // удаляем картинку с папки
    }
    else{
        echo 'изображение '.$img_a[$i].' имеет текущую дату <br/>'; //указываем какая картинка имеет текущую дату
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно начать отталкиваться от следующего скрипта

```
<?php
$arr[] = '2016-09-02_20-47-22.jpg';
$arr[] = '2016-09-02_19-42-02.gif';
$arr[] = '2016-08-23_20-37-42.png';
$arr[] = '2016-08-17_20-17-22.jpg';

foreach($arr as $filename) {
  $pattern = '/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})_(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/';
  if(preg_match($pattern, $filename, $out)) {
    if(mktime($out[4], $out[5], $out[6], $out[2], $out[3], $out[1]) < time()) {
      unlink($filename);
    }
  }
}
```

Вместо массива `$arr` и цикла `foreach()` в качестве источника списка файлов можно использовать обход директории с файлами, например, при помощи функции `glob()`.

```
<?php
foreach (glob("*") as $filename) {
  $pattern = '/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})_(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/';
  if(preg_match($pattern, $filename, $out)) {
    if(mktime($out[4], $out[5], $out[6], $out[2], $out[3], $out[1]) < time()) {
      unlink($filename);
    }
  }
}
```

Если время в файле не следует учитывать, то вместо даты и времени

```
mktime($out[4], $out[5], $out[6], $out[2], $out[3], $out[1])
```

можно формировать только дату, зануляя первые три параметра функции `mktime()`

```
mktime(0, 0, 0, $out[2], $out[3], $out[1])
```